# Pass An Object Between 2 View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, object, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to pass an object between 2 VCs, from a popover to the detail view of split view controller.

I think I need to use NSNotificationCenter.

I tried this but can't seem to get it to work.

In `didSelectRow` of popover

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PassObject" withObject:objectToPass];
```

In `detail VC`

```
    - (void) didReceiveNotificationPassObject:(NSNotification*)notification  
    {
        YourObjectClass *theObject = (YourObjectClass*)notification.object;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveNotificationPassObject:) name:@"PassObject" object:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just a typo when entering the question but in the first line where you post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PassObject" withObject:objectToPass];
```

the method signature is wrong - it should be 'object:objectToPass' not 'withObject:objectToPass'.  The line you have there will compile with a warning and crash at runtime.

Aside from that all the logic seems fine.

Comment: I get instance method `postNotificationWithName` not found warning with `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PassObject" Object:code];`

Comment: I'm also getting crash when running at that line: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:Object:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d750f0`

Comment: you need to use a lowercase letter 'o' i.e.  'object:' not 'Object:'.

Comment: thanks, works perfect, do you know how to make the popover dismiss now at `didSelectRow`?

Comment: going off topic  - but call [self dismissPopoverAnimated:TRUE] inside the didSelectRow method.

Comment: Are you sure? It says `dismissPopoverAnimated not found.`

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing? Does `didReceiveNotificationPassObject:` hit? If it doesn't, you could verify that `viewDidLoad` executes before `didSelectRow`.

Use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PassObject" object:objectToPass];` instead of `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PassObject" withObject:objectToPass];`

Also, don't forget to `removeObserver` in `viewDidUnload`.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: I get `instance method postNotificationWithName not found` warning with `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PassObject" Object:code];` also crash when running at that line: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:Object:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d750f0`

Answer (score 0):

A fast and easy solution to notify with multiple parameters is to call the notification it like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"shareButton" object:@"camera"];
```

Where "camera" acts like your parameter. Then

```
- (void)shareButton:(id)sender
{
   NSString *kindOf = [sender object];

    if ([kindOf isEqualToString:@"camera"]) {
         // Your code goes here
    }
 }
```